# phpstorm write issues in ./idea directory

Tags: linux, windows, phpstorm, chmod

When I try to save a file to disc within a project directory, I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: W:\\[projectname]\\.idea not found
```

Some research tells me, the (network) location is not writable. 
I'm trying to write this file from phpstorm in windows 8. 
The drive (W:) is a network drive to a linux machine.

The directory I try to write to is chowned to the same user and group as I connect with in windows.

This is a result of ls -alh:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 correct-user correct-user
```

Comment: You can save `.idea` in another location (e.g. your user folder, "C:\Users\USERNAME\My Documents\My Projects" for example) -- just follow workaround from http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-343

Comment: Hi Niels, thank you for your answer. 

I have found a different solution. I am now running vagrant on a virtualbox. Now my code is running in a virtual machine (Debian) which has no issues with files / dirs starting with a dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my samba settings I added a veto files parameter. Removing this parameter allows me to write dot files again.

Samba describes this setting as follows:
*This is a list of files and directories that are neither visible nor accessible*

Answer (score 0):

On Linux and other Unix-like operating systems files starting with a `.` are considered 'hidden files' by default. As such, when the Windows-based program creates it, it suddenly doesn't see it anymore right after since it's hidden, even though the creation was successful. You can fix this in your Samba config by adding the following line to the share configuration:

```
    hide dot files = no
```

Comment: Hi Niels, I added the hide dot files option as suggested, however it doesn't solve the prolem. P.s. I checked if the "hidden" directory is available at my linux station, and it is. 

The directory is also not shown within windows explorer

Comment: If you type `echo test > .hidden` in the shell, does the file show up on Windows in the share? Did you *completely* restart Samba after applying the configuration change?

Comment: I restarted both smbd and nmbd. 

I created the .hidden file and chmodded it to 0777 and chowned it to the samba user visiting the file. However it doesnt show up in explorer or PHPStorm.

From my windows machine it is not possible to create dot files. Is this possible in windows anyway?

Comment: Not in Windows Explorer (it requires a filename before the extension), you can do it from a shell though - the exact same command actually.

Comment: Ok, that I understand, and that I already did (created the .idea file within the project dir)

Comment: `.idea` is supposed to be a folder, and it will obviously fail if it tries to create a folder with a name that's already taken by a file.

Comment: True, but the deletion of the directory doesn't help :(